# Why are my USB flash drives not working well under Linux and Windows?

Tags: windows, usb-drive, file-format

Let me explain my question better: I am a Linux user (Fedora 20) and regularly need to use USB flash drives to carry files I will need to open in Windows computers in College, and the other way around. However I always have had problems with them. Most of the times the problem is that files on the USB stick recognized by Linux are not recognized by Windows, even though the stick is formatted in `Fat 32`. The solution I figured out to this problem is formatting the stick, but after a while the problems reappear.

I would like to know why this happens and how I can fix it.

Comment: Sounds to me like your USB stick is dying. Have you tried a different one?

Comment: Please describe exactly what you mean by, "the files ... are not recognised by Windows"